# Value of button element relative to a div or p with a jQuery click event?

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have seen several places in stackoverflow where folks have elegantly and easily turned a p or a div into a "button" with a click event in jQuery in an HTML based website.  I implemented something like that successfully.  The styling of these elements is easy and flexible.  Why use a button for a script-based click event?  They are harder, it seems to me, to style and position.  Is it simply a matter of personal choice, or is there a best-practices reason to use a button like one would do in, say, WPF or Windows Forms (or, dare I say it, Silverlight)?  I use input submit buttons for posting form input, of course, when implementing an ASP.Net MVC project, because the return to the server demands it.

Thanks for your thougths.

Comment: I don't see much reason to turn a `<p>` or `<div>` into a button when there's a perfectly good `<button>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a `button` or `input` element to submit, or perform other actions on, a `form` element (among others) simply because not everyone uses a mouse to navigate, or use, the internet. I haven't used screen-reader software myself, as yet, but given the popularity of `form`s on the internet I believe that they've developed an adequate user-interface representation for a `button`.

They don't, however, implement (or *reliably* implement) JavaScript to the same end, or effect, that you might for a visual UI.

So depending on your use-case, I'd strongly advise sticking with a generic `button` (or `input`). Failing that, leave the `button` in place in the HTML and remove it with JavaScript and transfer functionality to whatever element you'd rather use (if you must).

I personally can't see the benefit of using a block-level element as a `button`, but if it makes sense to you to discard the semantics, and inherent attributes of the `button` element in favour of a `div` or `p` (and presumably custom `data-*` attributes) that's your call. But please bear in mind that the internet should be usable for those that use it differently than you or I.

Comment: Cogent reasons for using a button.  Thank you.